# SwiftUI: Referencing Model Values in Nested Optional Arrays

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my app's view, I'm trying to list out the values of an array inside another array.  The arrays are being filled via JSON from an API call.  Both arrays are optionals.  I first check to see if the array contains a nil value.  I know in this case that it's not nil.

**I'm getting an error that "Value of type '[Landscape]' has no member 'mulching' "**

Here's the applicable portion of the JSON that's present:

```
  "projectType": {
        "landscapes": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "types": [
                    "mulching",
                    "clearing",
                    "planting",
                    "treeCare",
                    "other"
                ],
                "mulching": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "mulchingType": "Create new mulch beds",
                    "currentlyInPlace": "Grass / Weeds",
                    "currentlyInPlaceCustom": "",
                    "roomLength": "20",
                    "roomWidth": "4",
                    "color": "Black",
                    "customColor": "",
                    "length": "",
                    "approximateLength": ""
                }
              }
            }
```

My model is structured as follows:

```
// MARK: - ProjectType
struct ProjectType: Codable {
    let landscapes: [Landscape]?
    let generalConstructions: [GeneralConstruction]?
}

// MARK: - Landscape
struct Landscape: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let types: [String]
    let mulching: Mulching?
    let clearing: Clearing?
    let planting: Planting?
    let treeCare: TreeCare?
    let other: Other?
}

// MARK: - Mulching
struct Mulching: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let mulchingType, currentlyInPlace, currentlyInPlaceCustom, roomLength: String
    let roomWidth, color, customColor, length: String
    let approximateLength: String
}
```

Here's where I'm running into an error:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandscapeSpecificsView: View {
    
    let projectType: ProjectType
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if let landscapes = projectType.landscapes {
                if landscapes.contains(where: {$0.mulching != nil}) {
                    Text(
                        "\(landscapes.mulching)" **ERROR HERE**
                    )

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**How do I reference the mulching model values like mulching.id, mulching.mulchingType, mulching.color, etc.?**

Comment: You have to iterate over the collection of `landscapes` -- the error is telling you that right now it's an array, not a single instance. Perhaps you're looking for `ForEach`? Or maybe you just want to show *one* of them?

Comment: @jnpdx thanks.  It worked when I applied the ForEach functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reiterating what `@jnpdx` said,
in your code `landscapes` is an array of Landscape, and each element contains mulching,
but not the array itself. You could try something like this:
(making struct Mulching Identifiable)

```
struct LandscapeSpecificsView: View {
    
    let projectType: ProjectType
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if let landscapes = projectType.landscapes,
               let mulchings = landscapes.compactMap{$0.mulching} {
                ForEach(mulchings) { mulch in
                    Text(mulch.mulchingType)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried the solution above yours, but this looks very similar to what I applied.

Comment: @JohnGerard better to use keypath here `.compactMap(\.mulching)`